# Chef client v12 gives SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: chef-infra

On my computer, when I try to run `chef-client`, it fails with a mysterious error, even when I run it without arguments:

```
$ usr/local/bin/chef-client -z
[2017-11-20T18:02:07-08:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
[2017-11-20T18:02:17-08:00] FATAL: SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

The chef version I have is one that I just installed with `gem install chef -v 12.21.26`.  If I install chef version 13, I don't get this problem.

When I run `chef-solo`, I get the same issue.

```
$ chef-solo -l debug
[2017-11-21T13:12:08-08:00] WARN: *****************************************
[2017-11-21T13:12:08-08:00] WARN: Did not find config file: /etc/chef/solo.rb, using command line options.
[2017-11-21T13:12:08-08:00] WARN: *****************************************
[2017-11-21T13:12:08-08:00] INFO: Unable to access cache at /var/chef. Switching cache to /Users/buck/.chef
[2017-11-21T13:12:08-08:00] DEBUG: Current chef_repo_path is /Users/buck/.chef
[2017-11-21T13:12:08-08:00] INFO: Unable to access cache at /var/chef. Switching cache to /Users/buck/.chef
[2017-11-21T13:12:08-08:00] WARN: No cookbooks directory found at or above current directory.  Assuming /Users/buck/.chef.
[2017-11-21T13:12:08-08:00] WARN: *****************************************
[2017-11-21T13:12:08-08:00] WARN: Did not find config file: /etc/chef/client.rb, using command line options.
[2017-11-21T13:12:08-08:00] WARN: *****************************************
[2017-11-21T13:12:08-08:00] DEBUG: Sleeping for 0 seconds
[2017-11-21T13:12:13-08:00] FATAL: SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

What can I do to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

This might mean that your server doesn't have `localhost` set up correctly. In 13, we changed it to no longer actually bind the Zero server on localhost and do it via magic internal sockets. Just use chef-solo and it will go away.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't help. I added the log of that to the main question.

Comment: You can't just drop `chef-solo` in, you'll need to actually _use_ chef-solo.

Comment: I was unclear. When I run `chef-solo` it fails in the same way as `chef-client`.